# Alter a column default not taking effect after using the statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to alter a column's default value using

```
alter table table_Name alter MODIFY col_Name tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

After executing the above command, I see 25 rows affected. But when I run

`select * from table_Name;`  I still see old value.

Moreover when I insert new value, I still see the default getting set as 1.Why is that?

Comment: changing the default won't magically re-write existing rows. it'll only affect NEW rows.

Comment: A default value is the value that get set if you don't provide a value. It does not change existing values. You need an update statement for that

Answer (score 4):

When you set a default (as mentioned in the comments) old rows do NOT get affected.

Your original rows will stay as they are. To change them you need to do an `UPDATE` query

```
UPDATE TABLE table_name SET col_name=1 WHERE <condition>
```

Now as to why your new rows aren't updating. Your syntax is wrong. This is the correct syntax

```
alter table table_Name MODIFY col_Name tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

There is no second alter in after the `table_name`

Comment: Oh ok. But I am surprised why is it showing 25 rows affected if my syntax is wrong. Does it alter anything else? Also I ran the query as you suggested, it shows 0 rows affected. And I tried inserting a new record and it still inserts default value as 1.

Comment: If it shows you 25 rows modified that means that you have changed the syntax of the column so much that it can no longer hold the data and must  delete and set the default or NULL. 0 rows is probably cause the new column type is matching and no major change is required. Why is the default 1. This is probably an error in your syntax, table names, variables etc.